# Intermittently getting .”SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed”

Tags: adal, claims-based-identity

1. We have deployed our services on - AKS aks version 1.16.9.
2. Our services have been developed using a wrapper library to authenticate token which internally uses Microsoft.Identity.Model.Token to validate the token. In most scenarios it works perfectly fine. It has been configured to accept azure adb2c tokens as well as azure ad client credential tokens.
3. Once in a while (sometimes once in two months) we are getting the SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException- error only when we use the azure adb2b client credential token. The same library works perfectly fine using azure ad b2c tokens. Sample snippet from the component

```
 static Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters TokenValidationParameters(AppConfig appConfig)
    {
        var audiences = new List<string> {'audience1', 'audience2'};
        var issuers = new List<string> {'b2c', 'ad', 'auth0', 'identityserver'};
        var discoveryendpoints = new List<string> {'b2c meta url', 'ad meta url', 'auth0 meta url', 'identityserver meta url'};
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdSigningConfigs = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration();
        foreach (var discoveryendpoint in discoveryendpoints)
        {
            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(discoveryendpoint, new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
            foreach (var item in config.SigningKeys)
            {
                openIdSigningConfigs.SigningKeys.Add(item);
            }
        }
        var tvps = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidAudiences = audiences,
            ValidIssuers = issuers,
            IssuerSigningKeys = openIdSigningConfigs.SigningKeys
        };
        return tvps;
    }

services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 
        .AddJwtBearer( 
                options => 
        { 
                options.TokenValidationParameters = TokenValidationParameters(tokenconfig); 
        });
```

Exception Details:

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[1]
Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature
validation failed. Unable to match key:"
kid: ‘’
Exceptions caught:

Please note the exception caught is empty. We have checked the kid of the token and Azure Ad B2B metadata endpoint match.
After we get the error we continuously get the error till the pod is restarted . Once we recreate the pod the exception vanishes

Components used ( "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens = Version= 5.5.0, Microsoft.IdentityMode 7.0.0,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer Version=3.1.3)

Comment: It looks like you got solution in [GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1523#issuecomment-682091241)

Answer (score 0):

We were handling the metadata end point manually and not aware of how to refresh the rolling keys.
Looks like this simple code snippet could do the trick out of the box.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
            options.Authority = "Authority Details";
            options.Audience = "Audience";
            options.MetadataAddress = "metadataendpotint";
    });
```

'''